# Finding high points in a zigzag plot with only one segment on the right

Tags: python, r, algorithm, data-structures, geometry

For a zigzag line graph like the following (nearby points are guaranteed to be either lower or higher, depending the center points are high or low), I want to find out all the high points where there is only one segment of the zigzag line on their right.

In this example, those points are indicated by the left ends of the blue horizontal segments. Each blue segments only cross the zigzag line graph once. How to compute those high points efficiently?

The worst case is to check all high points against all segments in the line graph. But it is not efficient. What is the most efficient algorithm to perform this computation?

```
# R code to plot the figure for the example data
f=read.table(pipe('curl -s https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMB1y.gif | tail -c +43 | zcat'), header=T, sep='\t')
# example data can be retrieved by the curl command above.
with(f, plot(x, y, type='l'))
invisible(apply(subset(f, z=='z', select=-z), 1, function(v) { segments(v[['x']], v[['y']], 1e6, v[['y']], col='blue') }))
```

Some programming languages are tagged. But programs in any language are fine.

[image]

Comment: You can adapt the standard Sweepline approach to solve this. Order points by increasing y-value, maintain a list of active segments, ordered by x-value. As you process each point, check if there's only a single active segment to the right. Of course, implementation is not trivial.

Comment: Are you referring to this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm

This page is not well written. Is there a good page that describe the basic ideas of Sweepline algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

Using sympy.Interval to maintain two regions, a "region with only 1 segment on the right" and a "region with 2 or more segments on the right" while iterating right-to-left.

We iterate right-to-left on the points.

We maintain two sets, `region_1` and `region_2ormore`, corresponding to the y-values with only one segment to the right, and the y-values with 2 or more segments to the right, respectively.

When we arrive at a point `(x, y)`:

- if `(x, y)` is a high point and `y` has only one segment to the right, then we yield `(x, y)`;
- we update `region_1` and `region_2ormore` by adding and removing the relevant intersections with vertical segment `i = [y, previous y]`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy import Interval, EmptySet

def high_points_with_only_one_segment_right(xs, ys):
    region_1 = EmptySet
    region_2ormore = EmptySet
    prevy = ys[-1]
    for (x, y) in zip(reversed(xs), reversed(ys)):
        if y > prevy and y in region_1:
            yield (x, y)
        i = Interval(min(y, prevy), max(y, prevy))
        new_2ormore = i.intersection(region_1)
        new_1 = i - region_1 - region_2ormore
        region_2ormore = region_2ormore + new_2ormore
        region_1 = region_1 - i + new_1
        prevy = y

## EXAMPLE USE
y = [6, 7, 0, 5, 2, 5, 2, 6, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 4, 9, 8, 10]
x = range(len(y))
plt.plot(x, y)
ipx, ipy = zip(*high_points_with_only_one_segment_right(x, y))
plt.scatter(ipx, ipy, c='purple')
plt.show()
```

[image: Highlighted high points on zigzag]

Comment: I don't follow the method completely. Could you help explain the idea of the algorithm in plain English? Thanks.

Comment: @user1424739 Is that clearer now?

Comment: @user1424739 I might edit later with a plot of the evolution of `intervals_1` and `intervals_2ormore`, which unfortunately requires a bit more code than just `plt.plot(x, intervals_1)`

Comment: Thanks. I still can not follow some explanations. For example, how are "regions" defined? How are they different from intervals?

Comment: @user1424739 They're unions of intervals. The region might consist in one interval, or the union of two disjoint intervals, etc

Comment: There is no reason to believe that the regions are contiguous. For instance with my example, when we reach the fourth value from the right, `region_1` will be `Union(Interval(4,8), Interval(9,10))` and `region_2ormore` will be `Interval(8,9)`

Comment: Do you know the complexity of your methods? How is it compared with the awk method by atl?

Comment: I just notice the test data is not exactly zigzag as defined in my question. The point at x=8 is not a low nor a high.

Comment: @user1424739 Just remove the point at x=8 if it bothers you.

Comment: @user1424739 As for complexity, the awk method in the other answer appears to be quadratic. My method is probably quadratic in the worst-case, although it's probably more efficient than that depending on how the interval operations are implemented in sympy.

Comment: @user1424739 The awk method is quadratic because of the double nested loop `for( sp in spy ) { for( tp = 1 ; tp < seg ; tp++ ) { ] }`. The nested loop corresponds to step 4 "Record the number of line segments that are to the right of the stopping point and contain the y2 value of the stopping point.".

Comment: @user1424739 Presumably sympy orders the intervals in a search tree to make the set operations more efficient, in which case the complexity would probably be n log(n) instead of n², but I wouldn't bet on that.

Comment: How to make that algorithm to a n log(n) time complexity?

Comment: @user1424739 When looking for `y` in `region_1` and `region_2ormore`, you want to be able to search efficiently without having to iterate on a long datastructure. But actually, I think in practice, `region_1` is only ever going to be a union of a small number of intervals (perhaps never more than 2 intervals?) and so is `region_2ormore`. In that case the algorithm is already O(n).

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

> . . . find . . . all the high points where there is only one segment of the . . . line on their right

### Process

1. Read all points into line segments (x1,y1)-(x2,y2)
2. Observe that a point can only be a high point solution if it is an endpoint of a line segment. In otherwords, all points along the line are not possible high point solutions and only endpoints need to be visited.
3. Prepare the order to visit (sweep) end points by sorting from low y2 value to high y2 value. Call these points stopping points.
4. Record the number of line segments that are to the right of the stopping point and contain the y2 value of the stopping point.
5. Report stopping points that have only 1 line segment to the right of the stopping point and contain the stopping point y2 value.

### Output

Here is the output for the requested data.

```
curl -s https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMB1y.gif | tail -c +43 | zcat > table.txt
./sweepline.awk table.txt   
stopping point (13346,38.9999) has one segment on right that segment is (13351,32.16)-(13392,50.99)
stopping point (13288,41.54) has one segment on right that segment is (13351,32.16)-(13392,50.99)
stopping point (13166,44.16) has one segment on right that segment is (13351,32.16)-(13392,50.99)
stopping point (13392,50.99) has one segment on right that segment is (13399,44.35)-(13404,53.52)
stopping point (13043,52.08) has one segment on right that segment is (13399,44.35)-(13404,53.52)
```

```
#!/usr/local/bin/gawk -M -v PREC=256 -f

# -M means use MPFR multiple-precision floating-point computation
# -v means assign variable PREC value 256
# -f read the awk program source from source-file (below)

BEGIN { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc" ; seg=1 ; CONVFMT="%.20g" }

# segments (x1,y1) - (x2,y2)

NR == 1 { next; }
NR == 2 { x1[seg] = $1 ; y1[seg] = $2 ; next }

NR >  2 {
  # step 1, read all points into line segments
  x2[seg] = $1 ;
  y2[seg] = $2 ;
  for ( newindex = $2 ; newindex in spseg ; newindex = newindex + "0.00000000001" ) ;
  # print "newindex=" newindex ;
  spseg[newindex] = seg;
  seg = seg + 1;
  x1[seg] = $1 ;
  y1[seg] = $2 ;
}

END {
  # Prepare the order to visit end points by sorting 
  # from low y2 value to high y2 value. Call these 
  # points stopping points.
  asorti( spseg, spy )
  for( sp in spy )
  {
    s = spseg[spy[sp]]
    # print "stopping point z" sp " y=" spy[sp] ": (" x1[s] "," y1[s] ")-(" x2[s] "," y2[s] ")"
    spright = 0;
    for( tp = 1 ; tp < seg ; tp++ )
    {
      # print "test point " tp " y=" spy[tp] ": (" x1[tp] "," y1[tp] ")-(" x2[tp] "," y2[tp] ")"
      if ( s == tp )
      {
        # print "same";
        continue;
      }
      if ( ( y2[tp] <= y2[s] ) && ( y1[tp] <= y2[s] ) )
      {
        # print "below";
        continue;
      }
      if ( ( y2[tp] >= y2[s] ) && ( y1[tp] >= y2[s] ) )
      {
        # print "above";
        continue;
      }
      if ( x2[tp] <= x2[s] )
      {
        # print "left";
        continue;
      }
      if ( x1[tp] == x2[s] )
      {
        # print "right neighbor" ;
        continue;
      }
      # Record the number of line segments that are 
      # to the right of the stopping point and contain
      # the y2 value of the stopping point.

      # print "count it"
      tpstr = "(" x1[tp] "," y1[tp] ")-(" x2[tp] "," y2[tp] ")"
      spright = spright + 1;
    }
    # print "z" sp " spright=" spright;
    if ( spright == 1 )
    {
      # Report stopping points that have only 1 line
      # segment to the right of the stopping point and 
      # contain the stopping point y2 value.
      print "stopping point (" x2[s] "," y2[s] ") has one segment on right that segment is " tpstr
    }
  }
}
```

I referenced material in [Line Segment Intersection Using a Sweep Line
Algorithm](https://www.cs.tufts.edu/comp/163/notes05/seg_intersection_handout.pdf), but made no attempts to reproduce the specific concepts covered in that paper.

Comment: Thanks. But I am looking for high points satisfying the condition specific in my original question instead of segments. I am confused about what is the output answering my question. Also, this algorithm uses double for-loop. Is it of the same complexity as the python answer by Stef. Stef's answer has one for-loop. But it is not clear whether there is any hidden for-loop in the interval operations he used.

Comment: Could you clean up and just print out the answers asked?

Comment: Could you please add some explanations on how this algorithm works?

Comment: Do you have any assumption on whether the first segment is going downward (top-left to bottom-right) or going upward (bottom-left to top-right)?

Comment: @user1424739, yes I will try to improve this to display only the high points and explaining where the algorithm came from, no attempts at optimizations are made, will include some references that discuss optimizations for line sweep algorithms

Comment: Is this algorithm robust against points with the same y values?

Comment: @user1424739, this specific code is not safe for input data where multiple y2 values exist, the sweep array would need to be modified so the index for sweeping is unique, for example adding a small offset everytime the "same" value was added to the ```spseg``` array.

Comment: But adding such a small value would make the result not same as the true result? If so, how to make the method robust against same y values, yet maintain the output is not even slightly deviated from the true result?

Comment: What is the time complexity of this implementation?

Comment: @user1424739, updated to handle matching y2 values. The ```spseg``` array is an intermediate data structure meant to order all end points from low y2 to high y2. The original ```spseg``` index is y2. The ```asorti``` function uses ```spseg``` as input to create the sorted array of stopping points named ```spy```.  It is ```spy``` that is used to sweep the end points and make decisions based on the original values linked by segment number in arrays ```x1```, ```y1```, ```x2```, and ```y2```.

Comment: @user1424739, ```asorti``` uses ```qsort```, in worse case that is O(n^2) so finding the worst case sweep path is O(n^2) and the nested for loops make no efforts at optimization so they are also O(n^2) which means this all is O(n^2).